# VBA Excel date generate

Tags: vba, excel, date

So.. i need a calendar where i just have to add two dates (beginning and ending of a project) so that excel automaticly generates ALL day´s without holidays and weekends.

But i have no clue how. What i also need is the time spent on each day per 8 hours except friday, it has only 6 hours. The second part shouldnt be that hard for me but im completly lost with the first part.

[excel_vba IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcu4P.png)

can you help me

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a sub that will loop through the days and add them into the next row. So a for loop using the start and end dates that uses dateadd (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php) to add a day on till it reaches the end date.

```
currentdate = DateAdd("d", 1, currentdate)
```

You could then, inside the loop for the date value you've created, add the date onto the last row in the table using something like:

```
NextRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```